# Do I need to perform a box-cox transformation for all individuals in a panel dataset?

Tags: panel-data

I am working with panel data and ARIMA models. Some individuals appear to require a Box-Cox transformation, as the Ljung-Box test statistic is large. Other individuals do not appear to require a Box-Cox transformation as the Ljung-Box test statistic is small (<0.05).

Can I perform a Box-Cox transformation only on the individuals with the large test statistic? Or do I need to perform it on the entire panel?

Comment: What inferences or decisions do you plan to make with these data?

Comment: I'm embarrassingly new to ARIMA models. I'm trying to see how incomes have changed over time. I would like to see if most businesses fit the same ARIMA model

Comment: Would it be acceptable both (a) to characterize the changes in income in different ways for different individuals and (b) not assume any statistical dependencies between individuals? If not, you would need to transform all data in the same way.

Comment: Yes, both those would be acceptable. Thanks so much!!